# How to automatically switch to another scene after an online video finishes playing, in an iPhone App?

Tags: cocoa-touch, uikit, mpmovieplayercontroller, uistoryboard

Here's the user story for this simple iPhone App:

The user clicks on the thumbnail and triggers the `MPMoviePlayerViewController` to play the online video (in full screen).

We know that after the video finishes it would automatically shut down the player, then return to the previous page.

I need: return to another scene, not the previous one with the thumbnail.

Is there anybody who could offer some help?
Thank you very much ahead of time.

Answer (score 0):

Listen for the MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification notification and then push your new view controller onto your stack.

More info about that notification, and the movie player view controller, here: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/mediaplayer/reference/MPMoviePlayerController_Class/Reference/Reference.html

*EDIT - Adding how to listen for notification...*

Here's how you can listen for the notification:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(playerPlaybackDidFinish:) name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification object:self.player];
```

where self.player is the movie player instance, and playerPlaybackDidFinish is a method you have defined to handle the callback :)

Comment: Thanks dude, that's very helpful, though I have to learn how to add that listener..

Comment: @user1529365 I've updated the answer to show you how you can listen for the notification.